# Nobody has access to a repository in Azure DevOPs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, repository, azure-repos

In trying to restrict access to an Azure DevOps repository, it appears I've denied access to EVERYONE, including myself and project administrators. It is now not visible to any of us so nobody can resolve the issue, but if I try to create a new repository with that name it says I can't because it still exists. Please help - I am desperate!

Comment: Sounds like you may need to contact Microsoft Support.

Comment: Could you please share your settings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [Look up the Organization owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/lookup-organization-owner-admin?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#look-up-the-organization-owner) and contact them, since

> The organization owner can provide permissions at any level within the organization or project.

To do so,

> 1. Choose the Azure DevOps logo  to open Projects, and then choose  Organization settings.
> 2. Choose Overview and scroll down to show the Organization owner.